# How to build a secure Django single signon between different sites?

Tags: django, single-sign-on

I want to integrate my Django web application with other web based products (most likely 3rd party non-django applications.)  How can I let other sites sign in their users to my site with a single sign-on?  How would I store the usernames and passwords for the 3rd party sites users securely on my site to sign on my users to the 3rd part sites?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some more ideas...

**OAuth**

[OAuth](http://oauth.net/) for non-enterprise app.  Django projects: [django-oauth](http://code.welldev.org/django-oauth/wiki/Home) and [django-oauth-consumer](http://code.daaku.org/django-oauth-consumer/).  Article: [oauth in Django](http://fi.am/entry/building-a-website-api-with-django-part-3-oauth-in/)

**SAML**

Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) is more for enterprise apps because it gives the "enterprise" more control over their own users and which of those users can access the app. This protocol is (was?) mostly driven by Google and friends (e.g. salesforce.com).

Articles: [SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) Service for Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation) and [Demystifying SAML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/saml-084342.html).

Python projects: [PySAML](http://github.com/tachang/PySAML) and [blog post](http://returnbooleantrue.blogspot.com/2009/07/pysaml-saml-20-toolkit-for-python.html)

Django integration: [SAML with Django](http://robinelvin.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/saml-with-django/) (not a complete solution... just a starting point. Uses PySAML)

**Information Cards**

IIRC [Information Cards](http://informationcard.net/quick-overview) are the Microsoft universe equivalent to SAML. Python projects: [Python Information Card Processing](http://code.bandit-project.org/trac/wiki/PythonInfoCard) and [Information Cards for Python](http://www.cdatazone.org/index.php?/archives/23-Information-Cards-for-Python.html).
Nothing for Django as far as I know.

**--Edit--**

There is also [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) ([User Manual](http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CASUM/Home)) which can be integrated with [django-cas](http://code.google.com/p/django-cas/).

And two more SAML projects I had forgotten about: [gheimdall2](http://code.google.com/p/gheimdall2/) and [python-saml2](http://code.google.com/p/python-saml2/)

Comment: FYI the two articles you link to in this answer (one on code.google.com and the other on oracle.com) are both dead links now. I found the new URL for the Oracle one and fixed it.

Comment: I believe what I found must be the article indicated by the broken code.google.com link and fixed that one too.

Answer (score 3):

Never used it, but there is [Django-sso](http://code.google.com/p/django-sso/).

Answer (score 3):

http://openid.net/

There are other possibilities, but I wouldn't sweat over them because OpenID is used by lots of people and is the largest one of its kind.